# Does $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g}$ imply that $f$ and $g$ only differ by a constant multiple?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both entire, does $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g}$ imply that $f$ and $g$ only differ by a constant multiple? For the situation that $f$ and $g$ are real and positive this is not hard to see, since they are log derivatives. But how to prove this if $f$ and $g$ are complex functions?

Comment: They don't need to be entire, just nonzero and holomorphic in a connected open set. If the domain is not connected, then it's still true that they differ by a constant multiple, but his constant may be different for different connected components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g} \Leftrightarrow \\
f'g=fg' \Leftrightarrow \\
f'g-fg'=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
(\frac{f}{g} )'=0$$